# OTP in pass-otp

Tags: passwords, one-time-password, totp

I have a question as I use pass: the standard unix password manager with the plugin pass-otp.

I also generate the OTP in Google Authenticator and sometimes the generated codes differ even though the input (secret) and the algorithm are the same.

Since it's also based on time I've sync both devices (Linux PC and Android phone). However, I still get different codes. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I came to sad conclusion that was overlooked but fixed as soon as I fired off `systemctl start systemd-timesyncd` - my system wasn't synced and was approximately running with 1 min delay. Therefore the sequence was sometimes valid and on the list of generated codes from the phone.